# Обрезать тег в строке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой блок

```
<div class="str">
  123 456
  <span class="rem">R</span>
</div>
```

строка может быть длиннее или короче (число), но в каждом таком блоке в конце обязательный блок `<span class="rem">R</span>`. Как можно в js или jquery взять из этого блока только число без `<span class="rem">R</span>`? т.е 123456

Comment: различные варианты http://stackoverflow.com/q/3442394/1216425

Comment: @teran, вообще не то

Comment: да ладно, там речь о том, чтобы получить контент дива без вложенных тэгов (т.е. текст) что вы тут и пытаетесь спросить.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var html = $('.str').html();
var index = html.indexOf('<span class="rem">R</span>');
var str = html.substr(0, index);
console.log(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="str">
  123 456
  <span class="rem">R</span>
</div>
```